# Socket connection already closed

Tags: sockets, lua

I use:

```
s = require("socket")
host = ... some host
link = ... some link

c = s.connect(host, 80)
c:send("GET ".. link .. " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: host\r\n\r\n")
page = connection:receive('*a')
print(page)
```

And this prints me the contents of a page normally. At start it gives me Connection: close. This means that my connection is already closed? But why since I didn't call c:close(). Do I need to add c:close() if I need to close the connection after the print or that will be unnecessary? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the [`Connection`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.10) HTTP header.

It reads `Connection: close` (not `closed`).

And it has nothing to do, directly, with whether your end of the connection has been closed already or not but rather whether the client and server can consider the connection `persistent` or not.